# How to check KML layer has active feed or not?

Tags: google-maps, kml, feed, layer

I created a KML layer for the URL - http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/kml/nhc.kmz.

This layer is applied on the map and I could not see any layer. The reason is there is no active feed for this KML layer.

Is there any way to check if the KML layer has the active feed or not?

Comment: What are you using to display the KML?  Google Maps, Google Earth, the Google Maps API, something else?

Comment: I am using the KML layer for Google Maps

Answer (score 0):

If a feed is not active (meaning the URL fails to load) Google Earth will show the NetworkLink icon with a red network link error icon. The status of network link fetching is shown with different icons as shown below:

[image: Google Earth item icon]

Also note there are two validation errors in the KML, both in the target KML.
URL: http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/kml/nhc_active.kml

1) The NetworkLinkControl expires time is formatted in a non-KML date format.

```
<NetworkLinkControl>
  <minRefreshPeriod>120</minRefreshPeriod>
  <expires>Thu, 28 Mar 2013 17:01:37 UTC</expires>
 </NetworkLinkControl>
```

The *kml:DateTime* field is defined as the following:

```
<simpleType name="kml:dateTimeType">
    <union memberTypes="dateTime  date  gYearMonth  gYear"/>
</simpleType>
```

Recommend the ISO-8601 format: *YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:MM:SS'Z'*
like this: **2013-03-28T17:01:37Z**

References:

- http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp
- http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime

---

2) The Document has a name defined twice. The second name appears it should be enclosed with a missing `<Folder>` element.

```
<Document id="active">
   <name>Current Forecasts and Data</name>
   ...
   <ScreenOverlay id="activeLegend">
   </ScreenOverlay>

   ** following 3 tags don't belong here ***
   <name>Active Tropical Cyclones</name>
   <visibility>1</visibility>
   <open>1</open>

</Document>
```

Recommend using a [KML Validator](http://kmlvalidator.com/home.htm) to validate KML when it does NOT work like you expect it to.